# Need to escape two colons in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to select an HTML element using JQuery, and the selector that I'm using has two colons. I'm trying to escape these colons.

```
<div value="some::value_test"></div>

function escapeColon(selector) {
   return selector.replace(/::/, '\\\\:\\\\:');
}
var stringToEscape = "some::value_test";
var selector = $("[value|='" + escapeColon(stringToEscape) + "']");
```

My code above isn't working for some reason. I can get it to work fine when there is one ':' in the selector, but not when there are two.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Comment: "*I can get it to work with 1*" - how did you do that? do the same.  Works with just `.replace(/:/g, "\:")`  https://jsfiddle.net/w3mearun/1/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the method built in. [escapeSelector](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

```js
var stringToEscape = "some::value";

var elem = $("[value|='" + $.escapeSelector(stringToEscape) + "']");
console.log(elem.attr("value"));

stringToEscape = "some::value_test";
elem = $("[value|='" + $.escapeSelector(stringToEscape) + "']");
console.log(elem.attr("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div value="some::value"></div>
<div value="some::value_test"></div>
```

With your code, you are escaping the `\` too many times.

```js
function escapeColon(selector) {
   return selector.replace(/:/g, '\\:');
}
var stringToEscape = "some::value";
var elem = $("[value|='" + escapeColon(stringToEscape) + "']");

console.log(elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div value="some::value"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the issue is that there is also an underscore in my selector. It is actually var stringToEscape = "some::value_test"

Comment: Just realized this

Comment: And did you try this `$.escapeSelector` solution with your updated selector?

Comment: `_` is not a special character, so that is not going to break anything. So saying that is the reason is incorrect. My guess is something else is wrong, but since it is not the real code, it is impossible to know what.